# Add 1 where a substring is present in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have several strings concatenated in column rows, separated by '|'.

I need to make columns for each of the strings. so applyed a unique method and now have an arrange with the desired strings, let's call it A.

i made columns checking if the string in the A is in the concatenated row of column C with this:

```
for i in A:
    df[i] = df['C'].str.contains(i)
```

now this returns booleans, and now I'm trying to turn booleans into 1 and 0 values. The target is to make columns that tell if the string A is in the concatenated strings C.

So, is there a way to make it return values 1 for True and 0 for False? i'm asking also because i couldn't test much because A has 20 strings and C 20 million rows, so I have to let my laptop run this by night :P

hope my english is clear, thank's!

Comment: please post a sample small dataframe  which represents your original and demonstrates the issue. Also post an expected output dataframe  it will let us replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I have understood your question well you are actually just one function away:

```
for i in A:
    df[i] = df['C'].str.contains(i).astype(int)
```

However, if you already have computed the Boolean values you can:

```
df[A] = df[A].astype(int)
```

or

```
df[A]=df[A].replace({True:1, False:0})
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if this answered your question :)

Comment: Haha thanks! I meant the click at the tick mark beside the answer so that other people with a similar question understand that this is the answer :}

Comment: Oh, haha, well I need more reputation (15 reputation  to be precise) when I get that I will check it :)